# Retrieving Contact List using BackBase CXP?

Tags: android, ios, contacts, backbase

When using Backbase framework, [here](https://my.backbase.com/docs/product-documentation/documentation/mobile-sdk/latest/) is an example, in iOS or Android, do you know how to retrieve the contact list of the phone using this framework?

I haven't found enough documents nor examples that could be of help.

Regards,
Jeff

Comment: Put this question to BackBase forum also. https://my.backbase.com

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use the contact list from a web widget? If that is the case, you can use Plugins.

https://my.backbase.com/docs/product-documentation/documentation//mobile-sdk/latest/plugins.html

With plugins, you can create your own native component (Android/iOS) and expose features to the javascript environment.

PD. I am the product owner of the Mobile SDK from Backbase.